# Access Control Allow Origin header not present with fetch api call

Tags: ajax, go, same-origin-policy

So I'm trying to use isomorphic-fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

I have a server written in go that is giving back JSON data. This is how I'm making the call -

```
export function fetchDistricts(geoState) {

    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestDistricts(geoState));


        return fetch(`http://localhost:8100/districts/`)
            .then(response => {console.log(response);})
            .then(json => {
                console.log("json");
            });
}
```

I get this error in the chrome console

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8100/districts/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is weird, because in my handler I am doing this

```
func getDistricts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/jsonp;charset=UTF-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * from districts")
    //other code here
```

Further, this was working

```
var activitiesDfD =  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8100/district/1/activities",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
});

$.when(activitiesDfD).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
```

Why would this fail when using the fetch API and how do I get around this?

Edit-

I've now tried this

```
func getDistricts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/jsonp;charset=UTF-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get(`origin`))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
```

Incorporating the two suggestions below - but the error is the same.

Comment: In your *jQuery* example, you're calling `localhost:81000` and in your *fetch* one, you're calling `localhost:8100`. Is that a typo in the question, or can it be the error you're trying to find?

Comment: That's a typo - sorry about that - changing

Comment: I don't know what language your server is, but are you calling `w.WriteHeader` _before_ setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: The language is golang, err - I am  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

Comment: If you rearrange them to set the header before `WriteHeader`, it will likely work. As it is, you are setting the header on the object after writing to the socket, so the header won't be sent.

Comment: Just inspect whether the header really arrives at the client (using devtools, fiddler, etc). If it doesn't, fix your serverside code.

Comment: ^That doesn't really help me at all - I'm trying to fix my server side code - that's why the handler is posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all web browsers reject the origin `"*"`. Therefore sending `"*"` as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header results in a same-origin-policy violation.

Fortunately there is a work-around. If you look at the [gin-cors](https://github.com/itsjamie/gin-cors/blob/master/cors.go#L155) code that handles this, what it does instead is to re-send the `"origin"` header sent by the browser. So to make `*` work, you'd have to do this:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", r.Header.Get(`origin`))
```

Comment: That changed the error, I now have a  net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - why is that happening?

Comment: OK, I tried the new version and I get the previous error now.

Comment: Can you try it without https? The SSL error is unrelated to the CORS issue.

Comment: I did. But I'm back to the "Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8100/districts/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8200' is therefore not allowed access." error after doing r.Header.Get('origin')

Comment: Do I need to add the header before? If that header doesn't exist.

Comment: The origin header MUST exist otherwise the browser is non-compliant with HTTP1.1. Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera at least all send the Origin header. Can you check in your browser's Network tab to see if the correct header is indeed sent back?

Comment: what web browsers reject "*", and can you provide a link to an example? (it's always worked fine for me in FF+CH)

Comment: @dandavis: Chrome and firefox at least. Firefox allows you to accept "*" if you start it with some command line argument

Comment: @dandavis: Note that most middlewares understand "*" as a special flag to re-send the Origin header in Access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Weird. There is a  districts/ request, which has no Access Control header and the response tab tells me that it has failed to load.

Comment: @slebetman: no, FF accepts * just fine.ex: `fetch("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css").then(alert)` for example. major CDNs use "*", so it would be a bit surprising that it didn't work for anything halfway major...

Comment: ^So I put back the "*" - same problem. I'm now writing statusOk after setting though

Comment: @praks5432: Hmm.. then it's most probably a problem with the fetch function on js

Comment: what? That can't be right because isomorphic-fetch is a pretty well used library, it's more likely I'm screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this middleware https://github.com/rs/cors, and that got everything working correctly.