# redux isomorphic fetch Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have written a redux application which I am running locally using webpack-dev-server. (port 8080). I am trying to connect to a web service which is running locally at port 9000.

My code to connect to the web service is as follows

```
return fetch(`http://localhost:9000/movies/${dimensionName.toLowerCase()}list`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json =>
    dispatch(receivedDimensionAttributesSuccess(dimensionName, json))
  )
  .catch(error =>
    dispatch(receivedDimensionAttributesError(dimensionName, error))
  );
```

This receives an error

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:9000/movies/yearlist. No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response 
serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource 
with CORS disabled.
```

I googled for the problem and found this thread

[Access Control Allow Origin header not present with fetch api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722409/access-control-allow-origin-header-not-present-with-fetch-api-call)

but I don't like the solution which involved switching to a different library/middleware altogether.

How can I solve the problem with the isomorphic fetch library.

Comment: Does your web service allow CORS?

Comment: Ah.... I didn't know that CORS needed to be configured on the webs service side.I did a quick search and found this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter. After implementing this the problem was fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Answer (score 3):

[look at me,this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsS3a.png)

you  must use

```
let header = new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});
```

instead of

```
let defaultOptions = {
    url:'',
    method:'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    body:null,
};
```

to enable cors

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add `{mode:'no-cors',}` to disable the No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header. For more information you can refer the following url :

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api

```
return fetch(`http://localhost:9000/movies/${dimensionName.toLowerCase()}list`**,{mode:'no-cors'**,})
  .then(response => response.json())
```

Comment: This prevents the error from showing up by *removing the attempt to **read** the response entirely*. Since the code **needs** to read the response, this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is something you can control at client side. It is a security restriction for browsers that requires to be negotiated with the server.

A server can retrieve data from any end-point, but for browser apps this is different. For security reasons you are only allowed to load data via XHR from the same server you have loaded the web page. 
If you need to load data from a different server (say an external API) the browser requires that server responds indicating you are allowed.

See description in the "Cross Domain Request" section on http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2011/01/27/working-with-the-javascript-xmlhttprequest-object.html

Answer (score -2):

You can read this https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch

`fetch(url[, init])`

set the init param to allow cross-domain request

try